# Deterministic gas use

Tags: gas, evm, gas-limit, gas-estimate

In ether, any pure ether transfer will always cost 21000 gas.

However, due to the nature of the MPT used in the Balances tree, wouldn't some addresses have more layers of the tree to hop through and therefore use more gas? Sending ether to one address may require +/- 1 hops to read/update the balances state in the MPT verses another address, so why does the gas used not change?

I am wondering if this is principal also applies to smart contracts?

Given two identical contracts with a differing number of hops to reach the leaf in the State tree, would running equivalent code also use the same gas or would the gas used vary based on hops needed to get to the leaf?

Thank you for your answers.